# EOL while scanning screen literal when using urllib.urlopen (PYTHON)

Tags: python, urllib, eol

guys, so I'm learning Python and I've written this program:

```
import urllib

def read_text():
  quotes = open(r"C:\moviequotes\moviequotes.txt")
  contents_of_file = quotes.read()
  print(contents_of_file)
  quotes.close()
  check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
  connection = urllib.urlopen(r"http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check")
  output = connection.read()
  print(output)
  connection.close()
read_text()
```

I'm getting this error: EOL while scanning string literal. What am I doing wrong?
This is the file:

```
-- Houston, we have a problem. (Apollo 13)

-- Mama always said, life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you are       going to get. (Forrest Gump)

-- You cant handle the truth. (A Few Good Men)

-- I believe everything and I believe nothing. (A Shot in the Dark)
```

Comment: You have an extra set of quotation marks on this line: `connection = urllib.urlopen(r"http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check")`  Get rid of the quotation marks after `text_to_check`

Answer (score 1):

Exchange:

```
connection = urllib.urlopen(r"http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check")
```

with

```
connection = urllib.urlopen(r"http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check)
```

You have an extra double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that before.